# Solution Method for a Trig Equation

Tags: trigonometry

I was trying to answer a question someone posed about determining polar coordinates from the camera viewpoint from a photograph of the corner of a cube whose edges correspond to the $x,y,z$ axes. This involves transforming the angles between the axes from the photograph into the true angles via the viewing angle.

I came up with the equation:
$$\tan^{-1}(\cos(x)\tan(A))+\tan^{-1}(\cos(x)\tan(B)) = 90$$ where $A$ and $B$ are the measured angles from the photo and $x$ is the z polar coordinate.
Does anyone have a simpler way to solve for $x$ other than guess and check?

Comment: Presumably $90°$ ?

Comment: Yes $90$ degrees..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the tangent leads you to

$$1-\cos^2x\tan A\tan B=0$$

or

$$x=\arccos\sqrt{\cot A\cot B}.$$

Comment: This works great, thanks.